# Can't boot to windows 10 after install ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have installed windows 10 on second drive before (sda2 - second drive has two partions)
After that i have installed ubuntu 18.04 on first disk (ssd drive). But now only boot to ubuntu, cannot go to windows. Even windows not show on grub menu.

When i press f11 for boot menu option at start and choose Second drive, it still go to grub menu screen (ofcourse still not show grub menu)

I have ever try some way but not lucky. Could you help me resolve this.

Thanks.

Update
 This is pastepin link after run Boot Repair, hope give you more info
  [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/npNPnMBnZP/)

Comment: i have tried but not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Windows 10 to GRUB OS list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list) and [GRUB can't load Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706734/grub-cant-load-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Just run the update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should solve the problem.

Comment: have tried but not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the boot order to first drive in F11 menu, otherwise it hits drive 2 which only has grub entry for Ubuntu.

EDIT: it might be F12, whichever settings menu where you configure the boot order, not the one to pick for a single boot.

Comment: now 1st boot order is ssd  driver (which ubuntu was be installed)

Comment: you have to set the first boot to the driver with Windows 10 on it, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: i have tried but not work.

Comment: Then I suggest googling around for instructions specific to your laptop model and brand!